# What is best practise for magic numbers in css?

Tags: html, css

In css, I often find situations that require the use of a "magic number" or a value that I can't guarantee won't break for other parts of my site. Often it involves an arbitrary amount of padding/margin.

An example is a section class that adds x amount of padding to top and bottom of an element. But depending on the size of the element itself, I might want that padding to be for e.g. 20px smaller on the padding-bottom. It would be the distance between subsections vs other sections. I could make lots of classes like bootstrap's, xm,sm,lg etc. so that I can have preset but uniform options for certain padding sizes but it feels like I'm just proliferating the magic number into more classes.

What is the best practice for this? Could I use those classes then, for situations that break them, override with an inline style tag? That in itself has problems with code neatness but I'm unsure what is a good well reasonable way to go.

Comment: You want something like [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_(stylesheet_language))

Comment: Also check out [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables)!

Comment: @NieDzejkob I'm new to web dev and already knee-deep in LESS so I was advised that learning SASS just for SASS is not time efficient.

Comment: @Sim "Something like SASS" does not have to necessarily mean SASS itself - LESS provides constants too.